# Реализация анимации и наложения моделей 3D

Tags: 3d

Доброго времени суток, в 3d графике практически полный 0, приветствуются развернутые ответы как для новичка (а еще лучше - новичка-идиота :))

- Как именно реализовывается анимация 3d модели с т.з. 3d моделлера (исключительно абстрактно) и как именно это используется в коде, как хранится и передается информация об анимации?
- Как реализовывается наложение (опять таки, теоретически с т.з. моделлинга и практически с т.з. кода)? Т.е., допустим, есть 10 персонажей, которым нужно "одеть" шлем.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сначала стоит разобраться со статической 3D моделью.

Статическая трехмерная модель состоит из массива вертексов, массива индексов и массива стрипованных индексов. Каждый вертекс имеет три пространственные координаты, две(или 3 в случае UVW mappinga) на каждую текстуру которую хотят на нее наложить текстурные координаты, нормальный вектор и цвет.

```
struct vertex
{
float[3] xyz;
float[2] UV;
float[2] UV1;
float[3] NXNYNZ;
float[4] RGBA;
}

vertex verticies[100]; //Для примера возьмем 100 вертексов.
```

Полигон(треугольник) состоит из трех вертексов.

```
 unsigned short indicies
 {
 12,13,34, //1ый треуглоьник(Берем 12,13 и 34 вертекс из Verticies)
 34,15,2, //2ой треугольник (Берем 34,15 и 2 вертекс из Verticies)
 // .. и.т.д
 }
```

Затем индексы стрипуются(сжимаются особым образом). Подробнее надо гуглить фразу "Triangle Strips". Таким образом получается компрессия геометрии с помощью индексированной ленты треугольников.

Вертексы также можно сжимать. Я сжимаю таким образом

```
struct vertex
{
unsigned short[3] xyz;
unsigned short[2] UV;
unsigned short[2] UV1;
unsigned long NXNYNZ;
unsigned long RGBA;
}
```

Анимированная трехмерная модель = статическая трехмерная модель выгруженная для каждого кадра + интерполяция(так называемая keyframe, morphing анимация). Либо статическая трехмерная модель и набор костей и кватернионов которые описывают как надо разворачивать кости(RagDoll).

В моем движке процесс выгрузки реализован примерно таким образом:

1) Плагин с GUI для 3DSMax написанный на MAXScript выгружает все что можно выдрать из 3DSMAX в .h файл.

2) Этот .h файл крепится через макрос к C++ проекту двжика.

3) Генератор вызвается через консоль движка и дает на выходе на основании написанной спецификации бинарный файл, который движок загружает в оперативную память во время загрузки уровня.

В реальности все это вместе с чтением занимает ~250кБ С++/MaxScript кода, т.к. возникает очень много подводных камней(который естественно ни один из составляющих подобные интернет инструкции не описывает), вроде того как быть с нормалями для треугольников, как выгружать материалы, как быть с несколькими типами анимаций, как загружать файл на трех разных платформах учитывая endianess,существование в 3DS так называемых текстурных и цветовых вертексов и их несоответствия с геометрическими вертексами и.т.д и.т.п.

Спецификация на формат занимает около 20 страниц Word документа. При этом кости не поддерживаются, т.к. у меня очень много объектов и вид сверху.

Если вы новичок и не занимаетесь этим профессионально лучше возьмите готовый выгрузчик/загрузчик/спецификацию из Unreal или Quake/Doom или откуда нибудь еще.

P.S. Чтобы реализовать наложение нужно домножить вертексы шлема на соответствующую матрицу.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ.

@igumnov, конечно-же, я, немного, соврал когда написал что я практически полный 0. О том как хранятся данные статической модели я знаю, писать выгрузку модели я не собираюсь ( максимум немного видоизменю формат данных ), да и писать я буду не на C++.

Вот еще что - если реализовать скелет модели, есть ли возможность потом, при условии "правильной" выгрузки модели и использования "правильного" инструмента перемещать их програмно, т.е. что-то типа:


     Character.Hands.Left.move(...);

Или, обычно, все это строго задача моделлера?

Comment: Если вы делаете keyframe анимацию то все анимирует моделлер, при этом модель стоит на месте, а ноги болтаются если она например идет. Потом просто копируете вертексы в шейдер, домножаете там на матрицу мировых координат и все. 

Если речь идет о костях то моделлер просто вставляет туда скелет и все дальше вы умножая координаты кости на кватернион(q*v*q^-1) и интерполируя анимируйте меш как хотите прямо в коде. Теоретически к этому можно привязать любую объектную модель. 

Можно конечно сделать так чтобы моделлер санимировал все через скелет и потом выгрузить это как keyframe.

Comment: @igumnov - благодарю, с этим понятно, по поводу наложения - не требуется ли, все-таки, каких-то дополнительных действий? Просто домножить и все всегда будет ок?

Comment: Да изменение масштаба, перемещение и вращение можно реализовать домножением на матрицу. Чтобы надеть шлем ведь достаточно его перенести в нужную точку и все. Можно пойти правда и другим путем. Просто не грузить шлем в шейдер пока он не нужен. Но в таком случае нельзя будет реализовать анимацию того как он появляется.

Comment: @igumnov это именно то, что мне нужно, мне, пока, это не нужно

Comment: Не за что. Обращайтесь. Пойду дальше писать загрузчик.

Answer (score 1):

Моделлер рисует объекты в соответствующем программном пакете (Blender, 3DMax, Cinema 4D) путем манипуляции над точками описывающих поверхность фигуры. Т.е. вспоминая геометрию - сфера это множество точек находящихся на одинаковом расстоянии от центра и заполняющие все пространство вокруг центра. Для дизайнера это точно так же, но точек находящихся от центра не бесконечное множество, а четко определенное и они соединены гранями и каждые 3 грани имеющие общие точки образуют плоскость - треугольник, а множество таких треугольников образуют поверхность. Поэтому когда плотность точек описывающих поверхность мала, то фигура будет угловатой. Каждая такая точка имеет точные декартовы координаты в виртуальном 3-мерном пространстве. Поэтому манипулируя координатами точки или группы точек - изменяется и форма объекта. С точки зрения программиста тоже самое, но он видит массивы координат точек, нормалей, связей ребер и т.д.. И манипулирует путем изменения самого массива.
АНИМАЦИЯ это просто изменение координат точек в реальном времени с определенной периодичностью (N раз в секунду).
НАЛОЖЕНИЕ - это когда несколько объектов имеют одинаковые координаты во всех точках или в группе точек.

На самом деле, если желаешь заняться созданием игр или программой моделирующей что-то, то документация по OpenGL тебе поможет и обязательно книгу помощник, т.к. порог вхождения в эту область довольно таки высок, следует ознакомиться с большим объемом теории. Если есть возможность лучше использовать различные движки где вся эта OpenGL инкапсулирована и не прийдется перелопачивать кучу документации и засоряющегося кода.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, странно то, что вы тоже потратили так много времени на описание того, кек хранится и что из себя представляет 3d модель, я об этом знаю, кароче - не стоило. По поводу анимаций, вот я не уверен в том, что это всегда просто изменение координат и цвета массива структур, как насчет скелета? Или, в итоге, все происходит точно так-же, если да, то зачем тогда вообще он нужен?

Comment: Когда моделлер анимирует сложную модель, особенно если это персонаж, то ему гораздо проще абстрагироваться от редактирования многих тысяч точек и управлять скелетом и соответственно группой точек. Скелет по-сути средство упрощения работы для аниматора.